# How to use np.where in another np.where (conext: ray tracing)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, optimization, geometry

The question is: how to use two np.where in the same statement, like this (oversimplified):

```
np.where((ndarr1==ndarr2),np.where((ndarr1+ndarr2==ndarr3),True,False),False)
```

To avoid computing second conditional statement if the first is not reached.

My first objective is to find the intersection of a ray in a triangle, if there is one. This problem can be solved by this algorithm (found on stackoverflow):

```
def intersect_line_triangle(q1,q2,p1,p2,p3):
    def signed_tetra_volume(a,b,c,d):
        return np.sign(np.dot(np.cross(b-a,c-a),d-a)/6.0)

    s1 = signed_tetra_volume(q1,p1,p2,p3)
    s2 = signed_tetra_volume(q2,p1,p2,p3)

    if s1 != s2:
        s3 = signed_tetra_volume(q1,q2,p1,p2)
        s4 = signed_tetra_volume(q1,q2,p2,p3)
        s5 = signed_tetra_volume(q1,q2,p3,p1)
        if s3 == s4 and s4 == s5:
           n = np.cross(p2-p1,p3-p1)
           t = np.dot(p1-q1,n) / np.dot(q2-q1,n)
           return q1 + t * (q2-q1)
    return None
```

Here are two conditional statements:

1. s1!=s2
2. s3==s4 & s4==s5

Now since I have >20k triangles to check, I want to apply this function on all triangles at the same time.

First solution is:

```
s1 = vol(r0,tri[:,0,:],tri[:,1,:],tri[:,2,:])
s2 = vol(r1,tri[:,0,:],tri[:,1,:],tri[:,2,:])

s3 = vol(r1,r2,tri[:,0,:],tri[:,1,:])
s4 = vol(r1,r2,tri[:,1,:],tri[:,2,:])
s5 = vol(r1,r2,tri[:,2,:],tri[:,0,:])

np.where((s1!=s2) & (s3+s4==s4+s5),intersect(),False)
```

where s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 are arrays containing the value S for each triangle. Problem is, it means I have to compute s3,s4,and s5 for all triangles.

Now the ideal would be to compute statement 2 (and s3,s4,s5) only when statement 1 is True, with something like this:

```
check= np.where((s1!=s2),np.where((compute(s3)==compute(s4)) & (compute(s4)==compute(s5), compute(intersection),False),False)
```

(to simplify explanation, I just stated 'compute' instead of the whole computing process. Here, 'compute' is does only on the appropriate triangles).

Now of course this option doesn't work (and computes s4 two times), but I'd gladly have some recommendations on a similar process

Comment: Use masked arrays. They allow you to compute the condition, then compute other stuff only where the condition applies

Comment: Isn't condition 1 _very_ unlikely to fail? Meaning even if you were able to short ciruit you would save only a tiny fraction of evaluations of condition 2?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answers! I'll try first option and come back to you.
About second comment, it actually happens quite a lot in "simplified" meshes.
When checking the lengths before and after condition one, I go from 15k to 9k triangles.

Comment: @RolandSireyjol ah I see, I was fooled by your function name `signed_tetra_volume` which is not a signed tetrahedron volume but rather the sign of a signed tetrahedron volume aka orientation, I believe.

Comment: yeah, it's a function from another post, sorry for the confusion. Btw since we're only using the sign, dividing by 6 is useless.

On another point, note that this function sends back 0 for some specific triangles (probably when all 3 points are on the same line, I'm investigating it). As a result, conditions like s3=s4, or s4=s5 are not true, despite having the ray crossing the triangle). If you want more details about this, I can give some and update a fix once I find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I used masked arrays to answer this problem:

```
    loTrue= np.where((s1!=s2),False,True)
    s3=ma.masked_array(np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t0), r0t1)),mask=loTrue)
    s4=ma.masked_array(np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t1), r0t2)),mask=loTrue)
    s5=ma.masked_array(np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t2), r0t0)),mask=loTrue)
    loTrue= ma.masked_array(np.where((abs(s3-s4)<1e-4) & ( abs(s5-s4)<1e-4),True,False),mask=loTrue)

    #also works when computing s3,s4 and s5 inside loTrue, like this:        
    loTrue= np.where((s1!=s2),False,True)
    loTrue= ma.masked_array(np.where(
            (abs(np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t0), r0t1))-np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t1), r0t2)))<1e-4) &
            (abs(np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t2), r0t0))-np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t1), r0t2)))<1e-4),True,False)
            ,mask=loTrue)
```

Note that the same process, when not using such approach, is done like this:

```
    s3= np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t0), r0t1)  /6.0)
    s4= np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t1), r0t2)  /6.0)
    s5= np.sign(dot(np.cross(r0r1, r0t2), r0t0)  /6.0)
    loTrue= np.where((s1!=s2) & (abs(s3-s4)<1e-4) & ( abs(s5-s4)<1e-4) ,True,False)
```

Both give the same results, however, when looping on this process only for 10k iterations, NOT using masked arrays is faster! (26 secs without masked arrays, 31 secs with masked arrays, 33 when using masked arrays in one line only (not computing s3,s4 and s5 separately, or computing s4 before).

Conclusion: using nested arrays is solved here (note that the mask indicates where it won't be computed, hence first loTri must bet set to False (0) when condition is verified). However, in that scenario, it's not faster.

Answer (score 0):

I can get a small speedup from short circuiting but I'm not convinced it is worth the additional admin.

```
full computation 4.463818839867599 ms per iteration (one ray, 20,000 triangles)
short ciruciting 3.0060838296776637 ms per iteration (one ray, 20,000 triangles)
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def ilt_cut(q1,q2,p1,p2,p3):
    qm = (q1+q2)/2
    qd = qm-q2
    p12 = p1-p2
    aux = np.cross(qd,q2-p2)
    s3 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",aux,p12)
    s4 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",aux,p2-p3)
    ge = (s3>=0)&(s4>=0)
    le = (s3<=0)&(s4<=0)
    keep = np.flatnonzero(ge|le)
    aux = p1[keep]
    qpm1 = qm-aux
    p31 = p3[keep]-aux
    s5 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",np.cross(qpm1,p31),qd)
    ge = ge[keep]&(s5>=0)
    le = le[keep]&(s5<=0)
    flt = np.flatnonzero(ge|le)
    keep = keep[flt]
    n = np.cross(p31[flt], p12[keep])
    s12 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",n,qpm1[flt])
    flt = np.abs(s12) <= np.abs(s3[keep]+s4[keep]+s5[flt])
    return keep[flt],qm-(s12[flt]/np.einsum("ij,ij->i",qd,n[flt]))[:,None]*qd

def ilt_full(q1,q2,p1,p2,p3):
    qm = (q1+q2)/2
    qd = qm-q2
    p12 = p1-p2
    qpm1 = qm-p1
    p31 = p3-p1
    aux = np.cross(qd,q2-p2)
    s3 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",aux,p12)
    s4 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",aux,p2-p3)
    s5 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",np.cross(qpm1,p31),qd)
    n = np.cross(p31, p12)
    s12 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",n,qpm1)
    ge = (s3>=0)&(s4>=0)&(s5>=0)
    le = (s3<=0)&(s4<=0)&(s5<=0)
    keep = np.flatnonzero((np.abs(s12) <= np.abs(s3+s4+s5)) & (ge|le))
    return keep,qm-(s12[keep]/np.einsum("ij,ij->i",qd,n[keep]))[:,None]*qd

tri = np.random.uniform(1, 10, (20_000, 3, 3))
p0, p1 = np.random.uniform(1, 10, (2, 3))

from timeit import timeit
A,B,C = tri.transpose(1,0,2)
print('full computation', timeit(lambda: ilt_full(p0[None], p1[None], A, B, C), number=100)*10, 'ms per iteration (one ray, 20,000 triangles)')
print('short ciruciting', timeit(lambda: ilt_cut(p0[None], p1[None], A, B, C), number=100)*10, 'ms per iteration (one ray, 20,000 triangles)')
```

Note that I played a bit with the algorithm, so this may not in every edge case give the same result aas yours.

What I changed:

- I inlined the tetra volume, which allows to save a few repeated subcomputations
- I replace one of the ray ends with the midpoint `M` of the ray. This saves computing one tetra volume (`s1` or `s2`) because one can check whether the ray crosses the triangle ABC plane by comparing the volume of tetra `ABCM` to the sum of `s3`, `s4`, `s5` (if they have the same signs).

Comment: This kind of speedup can be quite useful, especially since I'm doing this process for a dataset containing 3.5k elements of 20k faces each, with 11k rays per element. Every bit of time saved can make a huge difference ^^.
Thanks for the update, I'll try it.